# Parse Json response from CoinGecko API with dynamic variable

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I am trying to read the response from https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price (for example with the fields: ids=bitcoin) where the "ids" field can be any cryptocurrency.
In order to read effectively the response i must have a data class like this one:

```
data class PortfolioCoinsDTO(
    val bitcoin : PortfolioCoinItem
)
```

with an extra class:

```
data class PortfolioCoinItem(
    val usd: Double,
    val usd_market_cap: Double,
    val usd_24h_change: Double
)
```

The above code works only when declaring the cryptocurrency as a variable in the DTO beforehand. Is there any way to solve this? So for example you can map the variable of the DTO data class to any cryptocurrency? (i am trying to see if with deserialization there might be a soluton).

Comment: I changed my architecture to be able to make a different kind of request and get the result i wanted. I am still interested to see if anyone can answer my question though...